# Cat runs from food but then eats when I put him in front of it

Tags: cats

My cat will eagerly brush up against me and meow when it's about time for breakfast or dinner. I will tell him "food time" (the magic words) and we both go into the kitchen. I'll prepare his food and put it down, but while I prepare his food he sometimes will run and hide under a bed or hide in the bathtub. I just pick him up and set him in front of the food and then he eats normally. Has anyone else experienced this? I take him to the vet regularly and he is overall very healthy with no concerning issues.

Some background info: he is a 4 year old fully indoor cat, and I feed him a combination of dry and wet food twice a day. I adopted him from a shelter two years ago.